# find the estimator

Tags: probability, statistics

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$

$X_1,X_2,X_3$ form a random sample from the following p.d.f:

$$
f(x\mid \theta) =
\begin{cases}
{e^{-(x-\theta)}}  & \text{for } x>\theta\\[10pt]
0 &\text{for $x\le \theta$}
\end{cases}
$$

there are three estimator of $\theta$, $\hat\theta_1=X_3-1$, $\hat\theta_2=Y_1=\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$, $\hat\theta_3 = {1\over3}(X_1+X_2+X_3)-1$.
find $E(\hat\theta_i)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\hat\theta_i)$ ($i=1,2,3$),which estimator should be used for estimating $\theta$.

I have tried to calculate the E and Var by the p.d.f, and the following answer.(I am not sure if my method of solving and the answer is correct)

$$E(\hat\theta_1)=\theta,\quad  E(\hat\theta_2)=\theta+1, \quad E(\hat\theta_3)=\theta$$

$$\var(\hat\theta_1)=e, \quad \var(\hat\theta_2)={5\over9},\quad \var(\hat\theta_3)={1\over3}$$

so.the $\hat\theta_2$ is obviously a biased estimator,$\hat\theta_3$ seem the best choice.
but, I also calculate the M.L.E ,and find the following fact.
${d \over d\theta}\ln L(\theta)=3$, so, $L(\theta)$ is monotone increasing, so $\hat\theta=Y_1=\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$, $\hat\theta_2$ is the maximum likelihood estimator.

which should be used? and if possible, could anyone, please, tell if my calculation about the E and Var is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$

The variance you have for $\hat\theta_3$ is correct, and that makes me wonder if the variance you report for $\hat\theta_1$ is a typo, since that should be $1$.

But you should have $\var\hat\theta_2=\dfrac19$.

Notice that for $x\ge\theta$, $$\Pr(\min>x)=\Pr(X_1>x\ \&\ X_2>x\ \&\ x_3>x)=(\Pr(X_1>x))^3 = (e^{\theta-x})^3 =e^{3(\theta-x)}.$$

So $$f_\min(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\Pr(\min\le x)=\frac{d}{dx}(1-e^{3(\theta-x)}) = 3e^{3(\theta-x)}\text{ for }x>\theta.$$  You can use that probability density function to find the variance.

Comment: sorry, I calculated agian,and the variance of $\hat\theta_1$ is e. what the p.d.f of $\hat\theta_1$ do you think?is it $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} {e^{-(x-\theta)}} & \text{for } x>\theta-1\ and    0 &\text{for $x\le \theta-1$} \end{cases} $$ ?

Comment: and I use the formula $\displaystyle\int_\theta^{\infty} (x-\theta-1)^2*3*e^{3(\theta-x)}$dx , get the 5/9...

Comment: The expected value of the minimum is not $\theta+1$, but $\theta+(1/3)$.

Comment: oh,yes,I made a stupid mistake of calculation,you are right.how about the p.d.f and variance of $\theta_1$?

Comment: You need $f(x)=e^{-(x-(\theta-1))}$ for $x\ge\theta-1$ and $0$ for $x<\theta-1$.

Comment: ...I get it. which estimator do you prefer?$\theta_2$ is biaed but is the M.L.E.

Comment: One criterion for choosing among them is the mean squared error, which is the variance plus the square of the bias.  Getting an unbiased estimator by subtracting the bias cannot always be done because often the bias depends on unobservables.  But in this case it does not, so the MLE minus $1/3$ is pretty good.  Generally it's a good idea to an estimator based on a sufficient statistic.  In this case, the MLE happens to be the minimal sufficient statistic.

Comment: in addition,I also calculated the distribution of min{$X_1,X_2,X_3$}-$\theta$, is it f(y)=$3e^{-3y}$ for y>0 and 0 for y<=0?

Comment: The cut-off still has to be at $\theta$.  It's $3e^{-3(x-\theta)}$ for $x>\theta$ and $0$ for $x<\theta$.

Comment: why?the independent variable is min{$X_1,X_2,X_3$}-$\theta$,but min{$X_1,X_2,X_3$}.

Comment: The density you've written is correct for $\min\{X_1.X_2,X_3,\}-\theta$.  When you write min{$X_1,X_2,X_3$}-$\theta$ instead, it's hard to see the minus sign.  Your way of using TeX is consistently perverse.  Why do you insist on putting "$=$" and "$-$" OUTSIDE the math environment?

Comment: oh,sorry.you see,as a green hand,I am not familiar with these.thanks for your advice and kindness,I'll take note:)